# Network Load Balancer doesn't distribute the traffic if the server has another subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I just encountered weird behavior of Network Load Balancer.

I have 4 subnets in same VPC:

```
Public-Subnet-A (eu-central-1a)
Public-Subnet-B (eu-central-1b)
Private-Subnet-A (eu-central-1a)
Private-Subnet-B (eu-central-1b)
```

I have attached the Public-Subnet-A and the Public-Subnet-B to the NLB.

I have created an Auto-Scaling group. That group has the Public-Subnet-A and the Public-Subnet-B.

When a new instance launch by auto-scaling group then the EC2 server would have either Public-Subnet-A or Public-Subnet-B. That's ok.

I use 1 security group and **all subnets allowed.** So, **I can access from public subnet to private subnet.**

But NLB doesn't send traffic or **send** a few traffic to the EC2 server if it has **Public-Subnet-B.** If the EC2 Server has Public-Subnet-A then NLB sends traffic to it.

I can access that EC2 server, which has Public-Subnet-B via other EC2 server, **which has Public-Subnet-A.**

I can access that EC2 Server, which has Public-Subnet-B via other EC2 server, **which has Public-Subnet-B.**

Why doesn't NLB send traffic if an EC2 instance has **another** (in this is case it is Public-Subnet-B) subnet?

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: looking at netstat and iptraf

Comment: How are you simulating traffic to the NLB?

Comment: I have a code that is trying to access to the server via the NLB. Also, I tried access to NLB via Netcat. It provided same result: http://paste.debian.net/plainh/9cbbedd2

Answer (score 2):

What address(es) are you testing from? Network load balancing uses a fairly rudimentary hashing algorithm based on src/dst IP addresses and ports, so if you're using very similar addresses to test you're almost always going to wind up going to the same node thanks to the hashing algorithm.